# Getting java.lang.NullPointerException at line System.out.println(record.get("TemperatureF")) don't know why

Tags: java, object, nullpointerexception, reference

> I am getting a `NullPointerException` at line `System.out.println(record.get("TemperatureF"))`. I dont know why.
>   I think that `record =coldestHourInFile(parser);` is not initializing record object as it is working fine if I create another `CSVRecord` object and initalize record object through that.

```
public void testMultiplefile()
{
    DirectoryResource dr=new DirectoryResource();//for accessing multiple csv files
    CSVRecord record =null;
    File f1=null;       
    for(File f:dr.selectedFiles())
    {
        FileResource fr=new FileResource(f);//c
        CSVParser parser=fr.getCSVParser();
        if(record==null)
        {
            record=coldestHourInFile(parser);  
            f1=f;
        }
        else
        {
            if(Double.parseDouble(record.get("TemperatureF")) > 
               Double.parseDouble(coldestHourInFile(parser).get("TemperatureF")))
            {
                f1=f;
                record=coldestHourInFile(parser);//changing record reference
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(f1.getName());//printing csv file name
    System.out.println(record.get("TemperatureF"));//printing record temperature column
}
```

Comment: You should really include the stack trace when you post like this. Errors are here to help, not hurt.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line:

```
record=coldestHourInFile(parser);
```

If colerstHourInFile returns null you get NullPointerException in last line of your program.

Comment: Yeah you are right i debugged the code last night and i got to know that  after the execution of coldestHourInFile(parser) in if condition the reference of parser moved to the end so when record =coldestHourInFile(parser) executes parser CHIF(parser) is giving null.   But if i add one more statement in that if condition like parser =fr.getCSVParser() then i initialize record with that CHIF(parser) then it works fine.

Comment: If this is the correct answer, you should accept the answer.